# find numbers in string vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

the data in the sql column like that

```
BLT Salad $4.50 Ham N Cheese Panini w/Chips or Soup  $3.99 Chicken Noodle Soup
```

I want to add `<br />` after the price. (the price might change but $  will always be there) to be like that

```
BLT Salad $4.50
Ham N Cheese Panini w/Chips or Soup  $3.99
Chicken Noodle Soup
```

is there is anyway to add new line after two char after the (.) or 4 char after the ($) in the price?
Thanks

Comment: You want `$4.50` to become `$    4.50`?

Comment: no i want to add new line (br /> after the price ( $0.00 <br/>)

Comment: is this a record from database?

Comment: yes it comes from the database and i can't change it there because other pages use it like that.

Comment: Are the numbers always a `$` followed by some digits, followed by a `.` followed by 2 digits?

Comment: yes this will not change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex, and assuming the numbers are always a $ followed by some digits, followed by a . followed by 2 digits:

```
Regex.Repalce(myString, "(\$\d+\.\d\d)", "$1<br />")
```

Breakdown of the regular expression:

```
(      - Start capturing group
\$     - Match `$` sign
\d+    - Followed by one or more digit (replace with [0-9] if needed)
\.     - Followed by a .
\d\d   - Followed by two digits
)      - End capturing group
```

Breakdown of the replacement:

```
$1     - Use the value of the first captured group
<br /> - Followed by <br />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dim replaced = Regex.Replace(input, "(\$\d+\.\d{2,2})", "$1<br/>")
```